# bison parser compilation unkonwn errors

Tags: compilation, compiler-errors, bison, flex-lexer, parser-generator

I am building a parser but I have some errors that I could not solve them, I am nuw to bison and flex, please help me solve them and understand why they are happening here is my errors that I get:

```
   lexical.l:3:20: error: common.h: No such file or directory
In file included from lexical.l:5:
bison.tab.h:81: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before âyylvalâ
bison.tab.c:1155: error: conflicting types for âyylvalâ
bison.tab.h:81: note: previous declaration of âyylvalâ was here
bison.y: In function âyyparseâ:
bison.y:96: error: incompatible types when assigning to type âSTYPEâ from type âNODEPTRâ
```

here is my parser file bison.y:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bison.tab.h"
#include "common.h"
//int yylex();
void yyerror (char const *);

typedef struct STYPE {
    NODEPTR pointer;
} STYPE;

#define YYSTYPE STYPE

%}



/* Bison declarations. */

%token ELSE REAL INTEGER XWRITE WHILE END DO IF THEN XPROGRAM FUNCTION XRETURN XREAD VAR FOR XBEGIN CALL ID NUM  
%token RELOP ADDOP MULOP ASSIGN AND OR NOT  
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc LOWER_THAN_ELSE
%nonassoc ELSE
```

Comment: Please post your flex file and the commands used to generate the .c files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `#define YYSTYPE` in your bison file, you need to `#define YYSTYPE` also in your flex file, because bison doesn't put the #define into the generated header file. You need to do this *before* you #include the generated header file.

Bison doesn't put the #define in the generated header because it has no way of knowing whether you did, since you might do it in an included file. In fact, if you're going to `#define YYSTYPE`, you should do it in a common header file, and `#include` the common header file in both bison and flex programs (as above, before you include the bison-generated header file).

Also, when you're regenerating the generated code, remember to always generate the bison program *first* because the flex program depends on the generated header file. That's the opposite order to the way you are doing it.

Just to make all this a bit clearer, here's an example:

```
 common.h:

   struct MyType {
     /* ... /
   };

   #define YYSTYPE struct MyType;


 lexer.l:

   %{
      /* All your standard includes go here */
      /* Must go in this order */
      #include "common.h"
      #include "bison.tab.h"

   %}

 bison.y:

   %{
      /* Whatever library includes you need */
      #include "common.h"
      /* Don't include bison.tab.h; it will get inserted automatically */
   %}
```

Comment: i did whay you have said and got this: 'code'bison.tab.c:1150: error: conflicting types for âyylvalâ
bison.tab.h:81: note: previous declaration of âyylvalâ was here
bison.y: In function âyyparseâ:
bison.y:91: error: incompatible types when assigning to type âSTYPEâ from type âNODEPTRâ'code'

Comment: What did you do, exactly? Where did you put the #defines?

Comment: @flashdisk I tried to make the order more explicit. By the way, it's not necessary to #include bison.tab.h in bison.y, and it's probably not a good idea, but if you insist on doing it, you must #define YYSTYPE before that #include in your bison.y file as well.

Comment: why it is not necessary to include it ? and why if I did that I should define YYSTYPE another time

Comment: @flashdisk, you don't have to include bison.tab.h in bison.tab.c because bison has put all of the contents into bison.tab.c already. If you include bison.tab.h, you're including the contents twice, but what is worse is that if you change YYSTYPE after including bison.tab.h, the two definitions are inconsistent, so you get errors. Really, it's a lot better to use %union and let bison manage the YYSTYPE, but if you insist on `#define YYSTYPE`, you have to worry about a lot of details, like doing things in the right order.

Comment: +1 but how did you know bison didn't put the define in the tab.h? i only dicovered this after trying to fix a type error becuase YYSTYPE was int (the default). the examples in the manual i've looked at just put the define in the declarations section. could you link to some documentation describing this behaviour?

Comment: @user3125280: It's true; it's not very explicit. But `bison` does not try to interpret the prologue (`{%...%}`); it just inserts it into the generated implementation. It does not insert it into the generated header file (http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Prologue.html). In modern bison versions, you can use the `%code requires` directive to insert code into both implementation and header files (http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/_0025code-Summary.html), or you can use `%define api.value.type`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the yytext error add this to bison.y :-

```
extern char *yytext
```

To fix the yyerror error make your prototype at the top of bison.y match the defn below :-

```
int yyerror(const char *message);
```

Fixing the yylval error requires a little more work and I don't understand this well enough to help. I'd suggest trying a simple hello,world type lexer,parser and move forward from there.

Here is the common.h I used :-

```
typedef struct STYPE {
    int pointer;
} STYPE;
```

And the header of lexer :-

```
%{
#include "common.h"
#define YYSTYPE STYPE
#include <stdio.h>
#include"bison.tab.h"
void showToken(char*);
%}
```

And the header of parser :-

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "common.h"
extern char *yytext;
#define YYSTYPE STYPE
%}
```

This gives me one error and a few warnings but those are due to the undefined functions. Note that I have moved the declaration of STYPE to the top of lexer and parser

Comment: thanks for you help,but it didn't change anything regarding yytext and the other errors!

Comment: I hope you've regenerated the .c files by rerunning bison and lex

Comment: #define YYSTYPE STYPE
you have defined this as an integer but I defined it as a pointer to a struct which is defined in the common.h file

Comment: ok I made it int because I didn't have common.h. Use whatever you have just make sure common.h is at the top.

Comment: I think you should not include common.h in the lex file because it doesn't use it!

Comment: Ok. I am not too sure either :)

Comment: why is that necessary why should it be on the top?